# ¿Hay alguna forma de retornar el resultado de una consulta Mongodb en python sin formato mongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

Verán tengo un problema al crear consultas con mongo obtengo los resultados pero con un formato como este:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('608fc14a19bdad630902aaf8'), 'Palabra_reservada': '¿Qué hora es?', 'operacion': 'detalles de tiempo'}
```

Pero solo requiero retornar algunos documentos o campos de la colección  y no todo el cuerpo del resultado de la consulta como '¿Qué hora es?
en python tengo algo así:

```
def metodomemoria(pregunta):
    db= crearconexion()
    rows = db.Funciones.find()
    respuesta =""
    for row in rows:
        if (row.lower()) in (pregunta.lower()):
            respuesta =row
            break
    return respuesta
```

mi idea es retornar un string de la consulta

Ya verifique el problema es que al aplicar rows = db.Funciones.find() python me lo regresa pero como cursor  explico de forma más amplia:
tengo un método para realizar preguntas:

```
def obtener_preguntas_respuestas():
   db =crearconexion()
   preguntasRespuestaXD=db.Funciones.find()

   return preguntasRespuestaC
```

y mando a llamar los valores vara compáralos inicialmente quería comparar posiciones en el método:

```
def metodomemoria(pregunta):
rows= obtener_preguntas_respuestas()
'''considerando que el metodo obtener_preguntas_respuestas()  es de tipo cursor'''
respuesta=""
for row in rows:
  if(row[0].lower())in pregunta.lower()):
      respuesta= row[1]
      break
 return respuesta
```

Así que tome en cuenta en sacar un arreglo
pero al usar db.Funciones.find().toArray no funciona en python al parecer es exclusivo en shell de mongo, motivo por el cual consideramos mejor extraer un fragmento para retornar el string o un array y no el cursor el siguiente método técnicamente con rows me regresa un cursor y pensando a que el método obtener_preguntas_respuestas() me regresa un cursos pensaba compararlos ya que me recomendaron comparar los cursores pero siento que es más complicado.

```
def metodomemoria(pregunta):
    db= crearconexion()
    rows = db.Funciones.find()
    respuesta =""
    for row in rows:
        if (row.lower()) in (pregunta.lower()):
            respuesta =row
            break
    return respuesta
```

La forma de usar JSON no lo he probado aunque tengo entendido que tendría o bien que usar un JSON o BSON  de forma externa el ejemplo que encontré muestra:

Comment: Mongodb trabaja con formato json que python puede manejar con el módulo [json](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/json.html). No te compliques.

Comment: No entiendo ¿cómo es la cadena que pretendes devolver? Puede ser tan simple como acceder a la clave de diccionario del campo que te interese retornar

Comment: @abulafia en este caso concatenar  "¿Qué hora es?" ,"detalles de tiempo"

Comment: No sé cómo funciona exactamente MongoDB, pero o bien lo que obtienes es ya un diccionario Python o es una cadena JSON. Si es lo segundo puedes convertirlo a diccionario Python con `dic = json.loads(cadena_respuest_mongodb)`. Una vez lo tienes como diccionario ya puedes acceder a sus campos `dic["Palabra_reservada"]` o `dic["Operacion"]` para hacer lo que necesites con ellos.

Comment: Tal como te comentan, debes convertir el resultado devuelto por la consulta en lo que deseas. Mongo siempre te devolverá un Documento BSON o una lista de documentos BSON. El *driver* para MongoDB de Python, tiene las Clases y Objetos reuqeridos para *traducir* este Objeto BSON en su equivalente Python. A partir de allí, debes operar con las propiedades de dicho Objeto en Python para obtener el resultado. De todas formas, hace falta que muestres cuál es el resultado deseado, ya que no queda claro en tu pregunta. Haz clic [edit] y agrégalo, no lo publiques como comentario. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya edite mi pregunta espero y sea entendible  en cuanto a JSON o BSON estos se generan de forma externa para cargar los datos en un arreglo desde python ?

Comment: @GeorgeLópez te recomiendo usar `aggregate()` en vez de usar `find()`, y dentro de `aggregate()` usa `$project` para mostrar solo el campo o los campos que deseas mostrar. `mongodb` siempre te devolverá cualquier consulta que retorne lista en un `cursor<Document>` y cada `Document` es un `HashMap` u `Objeto` bueno a partir de aquí puedes iterar el `cursor` y por cada iteración puedes obtener los valores directamente para un `Objeto` en específico y así hasta acabar el bucle o sino convertir directamente el `Document` a `HashMap`. Suerte.